# Applying the Taylor series

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods, taylor-expansion

For the initial value problem $\dot{y} = f(y), y(t_0) = y_0$, where $f(y)$ is smooth, we look at the discrete evolution $\Psi^t := y_1 = y_0 + h f((1-\Theta)y_0 + \Theta y_1)$, where $\Theta \in [0,1]$. Using the Taylor expansion (considering terms up to $O(h^2)$), I want to find the convergence speed depending on $\Theta$.

The standard solution suggests the following steps:

$$\Psi^t := y_1 = y_0 + h f((1-\Theta)y_0 + \Theta y_1)$$
$$= y_0 + h f((1-\Theta)y_0 + \Theta [y_0 + h f((1-\Theta)y_0 + \Theta y_1)]) $$
$$= y_0 + h[f(y_0)+h\Theta Df(y_0)(f((1-\Theta)y_0+\Theta y_1))+O(h^2)]$$
$$= y_0+hf(y_0)+\Theta h^2 Df(y_0)f(y_0+hf((1-\Theta)y_0 + \Theta y_1))+O(h^3)$$
$$= y_0 + hf(y_0) + \Theta h^2 Df(y_0) f(y_0)+ O(h^3).$$

The first two lines are clear. However, I have no idea how exactly the Taylor expansion is being applied from the second to third line. I assume once I understand that, I will understand the remaining steps too. Could anyone explain to me what's happening?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument of $f$ in the second line is

$$ (1-\Theta) y_0 + \Theta \left(y_0 + h f \left((1-\Theta) y_0 + \Theta y_1\right) \right) = y_0 + \Theta h f \left((1-\Theta) y_0 + \Theta y_1\right). $$

Taylor expansion at $y_0$ gives

$$ f \left( y_0 + \Theta h f \left((1-\Theta) y_0 + \Theta y_1\right) \right) = f(y_0) + \mathrm D f(y_0) \left( \Theta h f \left((1-\Theta) y_0 + \Theta y_1\right) \right) + \mathcal O(h^2) $$

(if $\Theta$ is fixed), which is precisely the term in the third line.

Next stept is again simply substituting $y_1$ although I think there is a $\Theta$ missing (which is not important as it vanishes in the $\mathcal O(h^3)$-term in the last line).